# Mendix to sap bapi integration issue

Tags: integration, sap-erp, sap-basis, bapi, mendix

We are using the Mendix public cloud hosted in AWS and trying to connect to the SAP QA environment hosted on-prem. SAP is ECC 7.0. We are getting a connection timeout error. We checked with the network team and they can see traffic on the firewall where whitelisting rules are set. Timeout parameter is set to 300 now. What can we do as debugging steps in SAP and Mendix to resolve this integration issues?

Comment: ECC 7.0 doesn't exist. Maybe you refer to ECC 6.0 EHP 7.

Comment: How much data are you transferring, is SAP actually able to respond in 30/300 seconds.

Comment: Also in mendix the timeout is configured in milliseconds. Just want to confirm you've set it correctly, the default value of that parameter is 30000, so if you want to increase it should be higher than that.